# Unable to view execution plan for CTAS query in Aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

While trying to migrate athena query engine from v2 to v3. I want to check execution plans for CTAS query to compare. Whenevet I press "explain" or run explain query on ctas query it outputs : `syntax error: destination table 'awsdatacatalog.db.table already exists'`.

This is my ctas query:

```
CREATE TABLE db.ctas_tbl with (external_location=s3path, format='parquet') 
as select * from db.tbl
```

Comment: I wonder whether it is not possible to create execution plans for a `CREATE TABLE` operation? Not sure what you'd hope to see from a plan of table creation. If you want to see how the `SELECT` portion would run, you could separately EXPLAIN that part.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Since ctas is faster than select due to writing to file in distributed manner, and can be written into parquet format. I want to see if there are differences in execution plan

Answer (score 0):

If you change the table name, does that work for you? Just a thought after viewing the [thread](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9896).

```
EXPLAIN CREATE TABLE db.faster_secret_glance with (external_location=s3path, format='parquet') 
as select * from db.tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

EXPLAIN applies to SELECT statements (https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html)
and not on CTAS.

If you want to know what is the execution plan to create and populate your new table.

Remove "CREATE TABLE ...." and place "EXPLAIN" just before "SELECT"